# How to blink( or animate ) particular subitem in gridview of layout

Tags: android, android-animation

Below is code that i am using to show my grid created using gridview, it has image and below that image text appears. and I want to make few of the text blinking for e.g. "image text3" and "image text5" so that user could come to know the difference between the text, that is blinking and the one that is not blinking. Could anyone plz help me.

```
GridView mGridMain1 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvMain1);
Resources res = getResources();
List<AppInfo> listAppInfo = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image1), "image text1"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image2), "image text2"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image3), "image text3"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image4), "image text4"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image5), "image text5"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image6), "image text6"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image7), "image text7"));
listAppInfo.add(new AppInfo(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image8), "image text8"));
mGridMain1.setAdapter(new AppInfoAdapter(this, listAppInfo));
mGridMain1.setOnItemClickListener(mItemClickListener);
```

Comment: You could add your animations to specific positions in your grid **within** your `AppInfoAdapter`

Comment: How do your `GridView`s items should behave when user starts scrolling `GridView`?

Comment: question is so unclear ... images should blink on what condtions ?
you can base your code on my example here http://selvin.pl/Blinking.zip sample app http://selvin.pl/Blinking.apk

Comment: if you are using adapter to show grid view you can add conditions in your adapter to show perticular area highlighted 
You can set your backgroung as per your requirements in adapter
first clear your requirement

Comment: To Blundell : could u help me to animate .

Comment: To selvin and Dipali : thanks for ur reply, and to make my question more clear, i have given image link here http://i44.tinypic.com/ix6mx2.png , in my application there are two scenario i.e. if user has registered then all icon will work on click but if user is running app without registration i.e. in evaluation mode then only two icon menu will be activated, and to let user know that only this two icon menu will work and other menu icon are deactivated, i want to blink the icon or text below the icon or both text and image. i hope now my question is more clear. plz help

Answer (score 0):

Well of course Android supports the blink tag out of the box! Just inflate a layout that uses it and you are done. See this commit: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/9c1223a71397b565f38015c07cae57a5015a6500.

Comment: undocumented, not working on 2.2 and without control over blinking (fx.: how to stop blinking?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only achive animation on subitems(`ChildViews`) of a `GridView` only by creating a ***custom adapter*** class that will tell which item to ***animate(blink)***.

Create a custom adapter using `BaseAdapter` class.

```
public class GridViewAdapterCustom  extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
List<AppInfo> listAppInfo;
    public ListViewAdapterCustom(Context con,List<AppInfo> list){
     mContext=con;
     listAppInfo=list;
    }
    public int getCount() {
         return  list.size();
    }
  @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
   @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row;  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemview, viewGroup, false);}
   //Add this code to whichever textview you want to animate
   TextView blinkable_text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   Animation myFadeInAnimation;
   Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.fade_in);
   blinkable_text.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
   return row;
   }
}
```

Create `fade_in.xml` file in `anim` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="50" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
 </set>
```

Create your own `listitemview.xml` file to initialize and set text fields